# Option tag with dynamic values generated at the run time

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, xml

I am using `JavaScript` in a `HTML` file and fetching data from `XML` file, I can read the file from `XML` and display as values in tabular format.

But my requirement is to get the values from XML file and pass it to a Variable for the front end

Example - I have an XML file with values as below enter code here

```
<data><Region>East</Region></data>  
<data><Region>West</Region></data>
```

after getting the value from XML file i need it to pass on to a variable in the front end as below
    Region - (With drop down and check box with the values) *attached the image for reference*

```
<body>
<form name="f1">

<select id="salesperson" > 
 <option value"">james</option>
   <option value"">john</option>  

<!-- instead of hard coding the above static value, i would like have it fetched dynamically from XML file using javascript--->
</select> 
<input type="button" value="Change Selected" onClick="changeSelected();">

</form>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Use ajax to get the xml file and parse it to create the `<option>` elements

Comment: Can you please share a sample code for Ajax to get the value dynamically, Actually i am using Ajax to get the values but not sure how to pass the value to a variable in the body tag as displayed in the image